# Accessing elements in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm having trouble accessing some elements in an object.
Here in my view file (aka HTML page), I'm initializing the c App.

```
  //Yh script tags are wrapped around this
  $(function() {
      App.initialize();
  });
```

Then in my JS file (this is a simple form of what I'm actually working on):

```
window.App = {
    el: {
        slider: $("#form-slider"),
        allSlides: $(".slide")

    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.ProductNewEvents();
            //bla bla
            // and so on
    },
    slideTiming: 800,
    slideWidth: 790,
    delegat etc
    ProductNewEvents: function() {
      //A whole bunch of events
       this.el.slider.click(function() {
           alert("Why you no work");
       });
       $("#form-slider").click(function() {
           alert("Why you work");
       });

    },
    some other objs
};
```

My problem here is I cannot call this.el.allSlides.some jQuery events or `this.el.slider`. Let's say `animate` or `click` in any of the objects. I have to fetch it from the DOM to bind any event to an element e.g. `$(".slide").animate`.

Comment: you can't call an object, only a function...

Comment: While I can appreciate you trying to lighten the mood with some humor in your post - don't over do it. Please clean up your post and remove any "fluff" that is not directly related to the problem you are facing. You can also take a few seconds to insert the missing capital letters.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what it is you're trying to access.  Can you add the calling code?

Comment: @landons Just want to access the elements i've defined in el. Eg instead of $(".slide").click i should be able to say this.el.allSlides.click, you get.

Comment: @php_nub_qq those were just two examples, i've tried it with different elements. btw i don't call a click function on it, was just using it to explain.

Comment: @lix I don't know what you're talking about :)

Comment: @Skyalchemist, you should be able to do that.  Just make sure `this` refers to what you think it does.

Comment: I have the feeling some information is missing here. I really don't understand what you are trying to do and what exactly the problem is. For example: *"I have to fetch it from the DOM"*... what is "it"?

Comment: @FelixKling Just edited it, hopefuly it's a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are doing, since I can't see all of your code. When you access your `App.el.slider` property it holds a reference to `$('#slider')` at the time it was created. To overcome this your code may have to look something like:

```
window.App = {
  el: {
    slider: function(){
      $("#form-slider");
    },
    allSlides: function(){
      $(".slide");
    }
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.ProductNewEvents();
    //bla bla
    // and so on
  },
  slideTiming: 800,
  slideWidth: 790,
  //delegat etc
  ProductNewEvents: function() {
    //A whole bunch of events

  },
  //some other objs
}
App.el.slider();
```

Comment: Interesting why are you calling App.el.slider(); at the bottom?